# ongo.MongoDataConfiguration.mongoManagedTypes exception while upgrading from spring v2.x to spring 3.0.6

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-mongodb

I have upgraded spring boot version and getting exception from Mongo.

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDataConfiguration.mongoManagedTypes**
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:183) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:144) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:410) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:283) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:344) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:115) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:565) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
at com.skurelabs.sprucex.SpringBootKafkaAvroApplication.main(SpringBootKafkaAvroApplication.java:50) ~[classes/:na]

**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @ConditionalOnMissingBean did not specify a bean using type, name or annotation and the attempt to deduce the bean's type failed
at** org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.validate(OnBeanCondition.java:489) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.(OnBeanCondition.java:438) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:155) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanTypeDeductionException: Failed to deduce bean type for org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDataConfiguration.mongoManagedTypes
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.deducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:519) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.deducedBeanType(OnBeanCondition.java:508) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.(OnBeanCondition.java:431) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
... 19 common frames omitted

**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoManagedTypes
at** java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.FilteringSpringBootCondition.resolve(FilteringSpringBootCondition.java:108) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.getReturnType(OnBeanCondition.java:527) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.deducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:515) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
... 21 common frames omitted

my pom.xml file

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.6</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <spring-parent-version>3.0.6</spring-parent-version><!--<spring-parent-version>2.7.10</spring-parent-version>-->
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```